# Shapes not rendering more than once in Fabricjs canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I'm trying to make a button that adds shapes onto my FabricJS canvas but the shapes only appear once... ish. Every time I click on the button below, the rectangle's border gets thicker which I assume, means they're being added but whenever I go to drag the rectangle, it displays as only one.

How can I make the button add multiple rectangles to the canvas? *(not all at once, after every click add 1)*

My current code:

**HTML:**

```html
<button onclick="addRectangle"></button>
```

**JavaScript:**

```js
var rec = new fabric.Rect({
    top: 10,
    left: 10,
    width: 66,
    height: 35,
    fill: 'silver',
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 1
});

function addRectangle() {
  c.add(rec);
  c.renderAll();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're adding the *same* instance of `fabric.Rect` to the canvas, multiple times.

When you call `addRectangle()` twice, two references to the same object end up in the internal `_objects` array - there's no safeguard to prevent that. During `renderAll()`, fabric.js iterates over the contents of this array and renders each element in it. That's why this Rect is being rendered twice.

What you want to do is create a new `Rect` instance on each `addRectangle()` call:

```
function createRect() {
  return new fabric.Rect({
    top: 10,
    left: 10,
    width: 66,
    height: 35,
    fill: "silver",
    stroke: "black",
    strokeWidth: 1
  });
}

function addRectangle() {
  var rect = createRect();
  c.add(rect);
  c.renderAll();
}
```